# Postgres UDT in C with nested struct

Tags: sql, c, postgresql

Hi Im trying to create a postgres UDT written in C. It's a fraction type. 
Im trying to experiment with the struct mixednumber with a int64 and struct fraction inside.

```
#include "postgres.h"
#include "fmgr.h"
#include <stdbool.h>

PG_MODULE_MAGIC;

typedef struct Fraction
{
    int64 numerator; 
    int64 denominator;
} Fraction;

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(fraction_in);

Datum
fraction_in(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    char *input = PG_GETARG_CSTRING(0);
    int64 n, d;
    bool valid;

    Fraction *result;

    valid = sscanf(input, "(%ld/%ld)", &n, &d) == 2;

    if (!valid)
        ereport(ERROR, (errcode(ERRCODE_INVALID_TEXT_REPRESENTATION),
             errmsg("invalid input syntax for fraction: \"%s\"", input)));

    if (d == 0) 
        ereport(ERROR, (errcode(ERRCODE_INVALID_TEXT_REPRESENTATION),
                 errmsg("denominator cannot be \"%ld\" in \"%s\"", d, input)));

    result = (Fraction *) palloc(sizeof(Fraction));

    result->numerator    = n;
    result->denominator  = d;

    PG_RETURN_POINTER(result);
}

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(fraction_out);

Datum
fraction_out(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    Fraction *fraction = (Fraction *) PG_GETARG_POINTER(0);
    char          *result;

    result = psprintf("(%ld/%ld)", fraction->numerator, fraction->denominator);

    PG_RETURN_CSTRING(result);
}

//////////////////////////////////////
// Mixed Fractions or Mixed Numbers //
//////////////////////////////////////

typedef struct MixedNumber
{
    int64 wholeNumber; 
    Fraction *fraction;
} MixedNumber;

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(mixednumber_in);

Datum
mixednumber_in(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    char *input = PG_GETARG_CSTRING(0);
    int64 w, n, d;
    bool valid;

    MixedNumber *mixed;

    valid = sscanf(input, "(%ld+(%ld/%ld))", &w, &n, &d)
            == 3;

    if (!valid)
        ereport(ERROR, (errcode(ERRCODE_INVALID_TEXT_REPRESENTATION),
             errmsg("invalid input syntax for fraction: \"%s\"", input)));

    if (d == 0) 
        ereport(ERROR, (errcode(ERRCODE_INVALID_TEXT_REPRESENTATION),
                 errmsg("denominator cannot be \"%ld\" in \"%s\"", d, input)));

    mixed    = (MixedNumber *) palloc(sizeof(MixedNumber));

    mixed->wholeNumber           = w;
    mixed->fraction              = (Fraction *) palloc(sizeof(Fraction));
    mixed->fraction->numerator   = n;
    mixed->fraction->denominator = d;

    PG_RETURN_POINTER(mixed);
}

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(mixednumber_out);

Datum
mixednumber_out(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    MixedNumber *mixed = (MixedNumber *) PG_GETARG_POINTER(0);

    char *result;

    result = psprintf("(%ld+(%ld/%ld))", 
        mixed->wholeNumber, mixed->fraction->numerator, mixed->fraction->denominator);

    PG_RETURN_CSTRING(result);
}
```

The Problem is when I retrieve a mixednumber column the value of the fraction part is wrong..
Ex

```
CREATE TABLE mixednumber_test (val mixednumber);
```

`INSERT INTO mixednumber_test VALUES ('(1+(7/8))'), ('(-1+(-7/8))'), ('(+1+(7/-8))'), ('(0+(-7/-8))'), ('(-0+(+7/8))'), ('(2+(7/+8))'), ('(9+(+7/+8))')`;

```
SELECT * FROM mixednumber_test;
```

result is :..

```
"(1+(0/0))"
"(-1+(32/4294967952))"
"(1+(94284056329736/16))"
"(0+(94284055669488/128))"
"(0+(0/94284056646312))"
"(2+(524/94284056644432))"
"(9+(94284055669488/16))"
```

Can anyone experts help me understand what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user data type cannot contain nested structures referenced by a pointer, since the data (especially the `Fraction *`-pointer inside the `MixedNumber` structure) is stored "as is" (and not recursively the data which it points to). So, if the pointer is dereferenced after importing a saved value it will probably no longer contain the original values.

You will have to provide all data in a contiguous memory block, perhaps by altering the definition to

```
typedef struct MixedNumber {
   int64 wholeNumber; 
   Fraction fraction;
} MixedNumber;
```

and changing the member access accordingly. Also don't forget to enlarge the internal length to now 24 byte (`sizeof(MixedNumber)`).